# WebSocket - Why am I not receiving the data I send?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm having trouble getting rudimentary WebSocket support working between a Python server and a JavaScript client.

After the initial handshake, the server sends some messages to initialize the client that appear to work just fine. These messages are sent in plain text.

The client responds with a key. After that, all further messages are XOR'd byte by byte against a key before being transmitted either way. This is done before the data is put in WebSocket frames on the server side (and the client, where the frames are handled by the browser).

At this point, things seem to fall apart. The server sends a burst of about 10 messages with lengths between 10-25 bytes and the client receives less than half of them. Furthermore, what the client receives may be corrupt as, after XOR decoding, they don't appear to be valid messages.

Originally I thought these problems were because I set the Text opcode in the WebSocket frames instead of Binary and the XOR'd strings were not valid UTF-8 characters. I'm now using Binary opcode and still have this problem.

I'm including the most relevant parts of my code here. I'm hoping someone can point out a mistake, or something I've overlooked. I've browsed the WebSocket specification, but I'm only interested in implementing the most basic message passing for my application.

Server:

```
def send_data(self, data):
    data = struct.pack('H', len(data)) + xor_encode(data, ENCODE_KEY)
    data = self.encode_websocket_data(data)
    self.send(data) // writes it to the socket

def encode_websocket_data(self, data):
    header = [chr(130)]
    length = len(data)
    if length <= 125:
        header.append(chr(length))
    else:
        header.append(chr(126))
        header.append(chr((length >> 8) & 255))
        header.append(chr(length & 255))
    msg = ''.join(header) + data
    return msg
```

On the client side I receive like this:

```
...
reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", this.process_input.bind(this));
...

// bound to socket onmessage, data = event.data
recv: function(data) {
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
}

// processes the input
process_input: function() {
    var bytes = new Int8Array(reader.result);
    var lines = [];
    while (bytes.length > 0) {
        var size = (bytes[0] & 0xff) + (bytes[1] & 0xff) * 256;
        bytes = bytes.subarray(2);
        if (size <= bytes.length) {
            var line = bytes_to_str(bytes.subarray(0, size));
            lines.push(line);
            bytes = bytes.subarray(size);
        }
        else {
            // error
            break;
        }
    }
    for (n in lines)
        if (lines[n].length)
            this.recv_callback(lines[n]);
}
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why I might not be receiving messages on the client side?

Comment: I'm also wondering if my lack of control frame implementation on the server could be affecting this, and if so, what is the bare minimum that should be supported...

Comment: Are you trying to implement RFC6455? If so, a) your code isn't conforming, and b) why are you reinventing the wheel - since there are multiple Python WebSocket implementation readily available?